# Trying programmaticly to space a grid layout evenly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack

I have a `GridLayout` which should show 25 Buttons spaced evenly. To be able to set an `onClickListener` without calling each one them I want to do that programmatically.
I made a layout resource file with the grid itself to bind it and being able to inflate it

```
activity.xml
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bingo_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:rowCount="5"
    tools:context=".BingoActivity" />
```

Now I'm creating the fields:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val bingoField = (1).rangeTo(25).toSet().toIntArray()
        binding = BingoActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.bingoGrid.alignmentMode = GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS

        val bingoFieldGrid = binding.bingoGrid
        bingoFieldGrid.alignmentMode = GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS
        bingoField.forEach {
            val button = createButton(it.toString())
            val gridLayoutParams = GridLayout.LayoutParams().apply {
                rowSpec = spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.CENTER, 1f)
                columnSpec = spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.CENTER, 1f)
                height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            }

            bingoFieldGrid.addView(button, gridLayoutParams)
        }
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun createButton(buttonText: String): Button {
        var isCompleted = false
        return Button(baseContext).apply {
            setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.red))
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            text = buttonText
            setOnClickListener {
                isCompleted = if (!isCompleted) {
                    setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.green))
                    true
                } else {
                    setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.red))
                    false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, the fields are auto generated without problems, but the spacing is not right:
[image]

I'm quite new to the old layouting, is there a way to easily achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating two different types of LayoutParams which doesn't make sense. LinearLayout shouldn't be involved at all.

The way they work is each child should get a set of LayoutParams that match the type of LayoutParams that its parent ViewGroup uses. So in this case the parent is GridLayout, so each child should be added using an instance of GridLayout.LayoutParams.

The way GridLayout.LayoutParams work is you define a row Spec and a column Spec that describe how a child should take up cells. We want them to take the single next cell, so we can leave the first parameter as UNDEFINED. We need to give them an equal `weight` more than 0 so they all share evenly in the leftover space. I'm using `1f` for the weight.

I'm using FILL with a size of 0 for the buttons so they fill their cells. The margins put some gap between them.

I'm setting height and width to 0 to prevent them from being oversized. If the rows or columns become too big to fit the screen, the layout goes way too big.

You might want to use MaterialButton instead of a plain Button, so you can easily tint the background color without simply making it a static solid color rectangle.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = BingoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.bingoGrid.alignmentMode = GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS

    for (num in 1..25) {
        val button = MaterialButton(this).apply {
            setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.blue_500))
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            text = num.toString()
            setPadding(0)
        }
        val params = GridLayout.LayoutParams().apply {
            rowSpec = spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f)
            columnSpec = spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f)
            width = 0
            height = 0
            setMargins((4 * resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt())
        }
        binding.bingoGrid.addView(button, params)
    }

}
```

AndroidStudio was finnicky about importing the `spec` function. I had to manually add this at the top:

```
import android.widget.GridLayout.Spec.*
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution but in landscape mode it makes it even worse. BTW. Its locked on landscape mode. :) I thought that it has something to do with rowSpec and columnSpec bc i saw some solutions with that. But I had no clue how to set it programmatically. Also your solution has somehow no effect. Its like without it (I edited my main code above, so you can look what changed)

Comment: Probably the views are too high. 48dp is maybe too much to fit five rows in landscape on a small phone. Once the total height of the rows is more than can fit on screen, the layout goes haywire when you're using weights. Try using my new code. 0 height and width and FILL the cells so they will always fit.

Comment: If I copy your code 1:1 its just empty lol. WTF At first i thought MaterialButton has some own constraint rules. So i fixed my styles that i can use it, but no. Its still empty. How does your XML File look?

Comment: I used your exact xml for the GridLayout. It works fine with Button or MaterialButton for me.

Comment: Ahhh, I forgot to put `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` back in! Now it worked, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider Google ConstraintLayout [Flows](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow):

To set the number of elements use `app:flow_maxElementsWrap="5"`

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/flow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="8dp"
        app:flow_maxElementsWrap="5"
        app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
        app:flow_verticalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then add the buttons programmatically to the `ConstraintLayout`:

```
val root = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.root)
val size = 25
val array = IntArray(size)
for (i in 0 until size) {
    array[i] = i + 1
    val button = Button(this).apply {
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0)
        id = i + 1
        text = (i + 1).toString()
    }
    root.addView(button)
}
val flow = findViewById<Flow>(R.id.flow)
flow.referencedIds = array
```

Hint: you could use `WRAP_CONTENT` for the button height to avoid stretching out the buttons height.